# What does "!<number> in C/C++ means

Tags: c++, c, operators, logical-operators

What does `!<number>` in c means. For example `!-2` or `!3`?

```
cout << !-2;

Output:
0

cout << !3;

Output:
0
```

Comment: Remember that a zero value is `false` and all other values are `true` (although you can't make that equality test).

Comment: Will we have a question for every basic concept of  the language? For example what that `-`<number> in c means.

Comment: @WeatherVane _"although you can't make that equality test"_ Why not? Are you referring to the underlying bit patterns? Equality vs equivalence? Or something else?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I meant that `3 == true` is `false`, although `3` in a logical expression is `true`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!` is the logical negation operator. From the C Standard (6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators)

> 5 The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of
>   its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand
>   compares equal to 0. The result has type int. The expression !E is
>   equivalent to (0==E).

And from the C++ Standard (8.3.1 Unary operator)

> 9 The operand of the logical negation operator ! is contextually
>   converted to bool (Clause 7); its value is true if the converted
>   operand is false and false otherwise. The type of the result is bool.

So, for example, this expression

```
cout << !-2;
```

according to the C quote is equivalent to

```
cout << ( 0 == -2 );
```

In C the result of the operator has the type `int` while in C++ the result of the operator has the type `bool`.

Pay attention to that in C++ you may use the alternative token `not`. For example the above statement can be rewritten like

```
cout << not -2;
```

In C you can include the header `<iso646.h>` and use the macro `not` as an alternative record for the operator `!`.

And one more trick. If for example you want from a C function to return an integer expression preliminary converting it either exactly to 1 or to 0 you can write for example

```
return !!expression;
```

That is if `expression` is not equal to `0` then the first applying of the operator `!` converts the expression to `0` and the second applying the operator `!` converts the result expression to `1`.

It is the same as if to write

```
return expression == 0 ? 0 : 1;
```

but more compact.

Comment: Made a small edit to clarify that this is logical negation. Good job for pulling the text from the standards so quickly!

Answer (score 1):

It's called a "logical not". The expression evaluates to false if the operand is nonzero and true if the operand is zero. Applying logical not to negative zero also returns true.

Answer (score 1):

Unary operator `!` is the logical negiation (i.e. NOT) operator. When the operand is true, the result is false  and when the operand is false, the result is true. Integers operand is implicitly converted to bool value. Zero is false and all other numbers are true.